# Blazor Bootstrap-5 Hover tooltip does not show up

Tags: c#, html, razor, blazor, bootstrap-5

On a plain html document using bootstrap, i added a field with hover function when hovering over the "info" button, as shown next:

[image]

And the full page content of my html page is next:

[image]

As shown above, the html adds a reference to both bootstrap css, icons (for the info icon) and js and uses a js function to make the tooltip showup on hovering.

While as shown this perfectly works on a plain html page, it fails in context of a blazor component. So in my blazor application i have the _Layout which references the necessary css, js and function as  shown below:

[image]

And my blazor razor component page looks like next:

[image]

And when i render the page and hover over the info button, the tooltip does not show (this in contrast with the plain html page where it shows up correctly ...):

[image]

Any clue ?

Thx for any response.

Emmanuel.

Comment: Your JS code is executed once on first render: we don't know if the HTML elements have already been rendered when the JS initialization code is executed.The same kind of issue happens if the HTML elements are rerendered. If you want to execute some initialization code in JS over HTML elements, you can use JSInterop.IJSRuntime in OnAfterRenderAsync() in the razor page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @T.Trassoudaine said, when your script executes the component hasn't rendered yet. You need to initialize popovers after the component renders using `OnAfterRenderAsync` lifecycle method.

Change script inside `_Layout.cshtml` to this. We define a method called `enablePopovers` that we'll call later from the component.

```
<script>
    window.enablePopovers = function () {
        document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]')
            .forEach(function (popover) {
                new bootstrap.Popover(popover);
            });
    }
</script>
```

Now in `PopoverTest.razor` add this:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS

@* rest of component code *@

@code {
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("enablePopovers");
        }
    }
}
```

Also check the documentation for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Hi Dimitris & Trassoudaine, yes, of course, JS will only work properly after page rendering of course, i should have known this . Anyways, the sample code shown above worked out for me, great thx to both of you 

Comment: An event better approach is to "wrap" the IJSRuntime in a separate project and create a C# wrapper function in your code-behind, like this:  protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
        {
            if (firstRender)
            {
                await BlazorJsInterop.EnablePopoversAsync();
            }
        }

Comment: And the library itself: export function enablePopovers() {
    document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]')
        .forEach(function (popover) {
            new bootstrap.Popover(popover);
        });
}

Comment: public class BlazorJsInterop: IAsyncDisposable
    {
        private readonly Lazy<Task<IJSObjectReference>> moduleTask;

        public BlazorJsInterop(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
        {
            moduleTask = new(() => jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
                "import", "./_content/Blazor.JSInterop.JsInteropLibrary/blazorInterop.js").AsTask());
        }

Comment: public async ValueTask EnablePopoversAsync()
        {
            var module = await moduleTask.Value;
            await module.InvokeVoidAsync(identifier: "enablePopovers");
        }